# Can I Two-Weapon Rend twice with four attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

I'm using two weapon fighting and have improved two weapon fighting. Now when I successfully hit with all four of my attacks will I add two weapon rend dmg twice, because I hit with my on hand and off hand twice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you read the [description](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/two-weapon-rend-combat---final) of Two Weapon Rend, you already know the answer:

> Benefit: [...] You can only deal this additional damage once each round.

Comment: Ya I noticed that the second time I read it but couldn't find a way to delete this question